# Submitting form with the radio button and not by submit button

Tags: html, forms, radio-button

I have a form  with many radio button in html and I want to submit the form using only radio button and not by submit button. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer uses jQuery*

```
$('.radiobtnclass').on('click', function() {
    $('#formid').submit();
});
```

`radiobtnclass` is the class  of the radio buttons you want to monitor

`formid` is the id of the form you wish to submit

Answer (score 1):

You can add an onClick event to each radio tag like so:

```
<input type='radio' name='x' value='y' onClick='this.form.submit()'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form name="yourForm" action="action.php" method="POST">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Radio button" onclick="document.forms['yourForm'].submit()" />
</form>
```